# Building REST APIs code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I am trying to develop REST APIs for my website. I am using CodeIgniter's PHP Framework. I have followed the tutorial mentioned on http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2--net-8814 to create the restful apis. The tutorial is based upon the code developed on https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

I have placed the rest.php in application/config folder and REST_Controller.php in application/libraries/

I have created an api in application/controllers/example.php

```
require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

    class example extends REST_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            // Construct our parent class
            parent::__construct();
        }
       function user_get()
        {
            if(!$this->get('id'))
            {
                $this->response(NULL, 400);
            }
            // $user = $this->some_model->getSomething( $this->get('id') );
            $users = array(
                1 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Guy', 'email' => 'example1@example.com', 'fact' => 'Loves swimming'),
                2 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Person Face', 'email' => 'example2@example.com', 'fact' => 'Has a huge face'),
                3 => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Scotty', 'email' => 'example3@example.com', 'fact' => 'Is a Scott!', array('hobbies' => array('fartings', 'bikes'))),
            );

            $user = @$users[$this->get('id')];

            if($user)
            {
                $this->response($user, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
            }
            else
            {
                $this->response(array('error' => 'User could not be found'), 404);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a .htaccess file as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

However when I send a GET Request to mywebsite.com/index.php/example/id/1 it redirects to the homepage. Could someone guide me

Comment: try this url mywebsite.com/index.php/example/user/id/1

Comment: @umefarooq it does not work that way. Do I have to modify routes.php ?

Comment: i have tried your controller with fresh install of CI 3 i don't have problem i have used this url http://localhost/ci3/index.php/example/user/id/1

Comment: @umefarooq it works when I test like how you have mentioned on a fresh install..but in my setup somehow it does not work :(

Comment: @umefarooq I have .htaccess file which redirects when index.php is present (RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]) I have setup a virtualhost on my machine. So when I access dev.myweb.com/example it redirects to dev.myweb.com . Any idea why it is not able to access my controller

Comment: I'm not sure how your library works, but regarding the .htaccess part, the following type of approach works (scuse lack of formatting):
RewriteRule ^partner/o/(.*)$ /path/ordering.php?recall=$1 [L]
... in this case it translates URLs of yoursite.com/partner/o/xxx into yoursite.com/path/ordering.php?recall=xxx . The script receives "xxx" in the variable $_REQUEST['recall']. Did you really want to pass the whole path without assigning it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Hope its working

try this

```
mywebsite.com/index.php/user_get?id=1
```